# Django Model Form not saving to database (No error message)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

As per the above  (title) my Django form is not saving, however, it does redirect to the correct page, the entry does not show on the admin page.

Please see the below code :

Views.py:

```
def newSetting(request):
    form = SettingsForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SettingsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    return render(request , 'main/newSetting.html' , {'form':form})
```

.HTML:

```
{% extends "main/base.html"%}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style >
  .row_container{
    line-height: 500%;
  }
</style>
{% block content %}
<form class="" action="{% url 'settingsHome' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.Complex }}
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="row_container" name='TRB-YTD'>
    <div class="row mb-.1">
      <div class="col" style="left-align">
          {{ form.Trial_balance_Year_to_date }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-11">
        <p> Trial balance YTD</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row_container" name="TRB-MONTH">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col" style="left-align">
          {{ form.Trial_balance_Monthly }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-11">
        <p> Trial balance Monthly</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row_container" name="IS-YTD">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col" style="left-align">
          {{ form.Income_Statement_Year_to_date }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-11">
        <p> Income Statement YTD</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row_container" name="IS-MONTHLY">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col" style="left-align">
          {{ form.Income_Statement_Monthly }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-11">
        <p> Income Statement Monthly</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row_container" name="AGE-ANALYSIS">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col" style="left-align">
          {{ form.Age_Analysis }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-11">
        <p> Age Analysis</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row_container" name="BAL-SHEET">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col" style="left-align">
          {{ form.Balance_Sheet }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-11">
        <p> Balance Sheet</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row_container" name="REP-MAIN-GL">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col" style="left-align">
          {{ form.Repair_and_Maintenance_General_Ledger }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-11">
        <p> Repair & Maintenance GL</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row_container" name="MAJOR-CAPTAL-GL">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col" style="left-align">
          {{ form.Mayor_capital_Items_General_Ledger }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-11">
        <p> Major Capital Items GL</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-NewSetting"> Save New Setting</button>

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import SettingsClass

class SettingsForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = SettingsClass
         fields = '__all__'
```

Models.py:

```
class SettingsClass(models.Model):
    Complex = models.CharField(choices=complex_list , max_length = 2 ,default='1')
    Trial_balance_Year_to_date= models.BooleanField(default = False)
    Trial_balance_Monthly=models.BooleanField(default = False)
    Income_Statement_Year_to_date=models.BooleanField(default = False)
    Income_Statement_Monthly=models.BooleanField(default = False)
    Age_Analysis=models.BooleanField(default = False)
    Balance_Sheet=models.BooleanField(default = False)
    Repair_and_Maintenance_General_Ledger=models.BooleanField(default = False)
    Mayor_capital_Items_General_Ledger=models.BooleanField(default = False)
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.Complex + ' Settings')
```

Admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import SettingsClass
# Register your models here.


class SettingsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(SettingsClass, SettingsAdmin)
```

If any body knows what could cause this , please assist , there are no errors showing when the form is submitted...

Comment: Try to check if `form.is_valid()` returns true. If not, you can check the errors in `form.errors`

Comment: @BrianD , I have tried to check if the 'form.is_valid()' is working by doing a 'print(request.POST)' . It only shows  "POST /settings HTTP/1.1" in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the template test.html to the catalog and try this in **views.py**, to check whether the form is saved or not, and so use the *print()* function in the console to find out if the program is being executed at one stage or another:

```
def newSetting(request):
form = SettingsForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SettingsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return render(request , 'main/test.html' , {'form':form})

return render(request , 'main/newSetting.html' , {'form':form})
```

Comment: The form still does not save, I have tried removing the "action" on the form tag , however, that doesn't submit the form at all ?

Comment: I have also tried changing the button to a input tag , that still does the same

Comment: Try to explicitly specify the fields in the form model by assigning properties to them, for example, 'complex = forms.CharField(required=True)' and so on with all the fields. Don't forget to declare the fields in Meta. The documentation will help you understand your code and understand where something goes wrong https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/